# MySQL how to do COUNT(*) on a query with joins?

Tags: mysql, join, count

Does anyone know how can I perform COUNT(*) on a query like this?

```
SELECT reviews.review_id, reviews.reviewers_rating, reviews.reviewers_name, reviews.review_date, reviews.pros, reviews.cons, products.product_name, products.slug, products.community_rating, products.number_of_votes, products.users_rating, products.thumb_link, categories.category_name_single
FROM reviews
LEFT JOIN products ON reviews.product_id = products.product_id
LEFT JOIN categories ON products.category = categories.category_id
WHERE reviews.approved =1
ORDER BY reviews.review_date DESC
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which column are you trying to count?

Comment: review_id, but only reviews to which all the other constraints apply. I.e. I don't need total number of reviews, but say to count just reviews of a certain product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Count(reviews.review_id), reviews.review_id, reviews.reviewers_rating, reviews.reviewers_name,  reviews.review_date, reviews.pros, reviews.cons, products.product_name, products.slug, products.community_rating, products.number_of_votes, products.users_rating, products.thumb_link, categories.category_name_single
FROM reviews
LEFT JOIN products ON reviews.product_id = products.product_id
LEFT JOIN categories ON products.category = categories.category_id
WHERE reviews.approved =1
Group By reviews.review_id
ORDER BY reviews.review_date DESC
```

Comment: You know that your result data will be limited to 1 record?

Comment: Because Count() is aggregate function and requires "group by" clause, when "group by" is not provided than all rows will be grouped.

Comment: @cichy, I hope it is fine now?

Comment: Anyway, the count column did return the right result, which is what matters I guess. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

Left Join's are not needed, same as order, and you don't have to count all fields, one will be enough

```
SELECT COUNT(review_id) FROM reviews WHERE approved =1
```

EDIT:
if you want to count reviews for products than you should make something like this:

```
SELECT products.*, count(r.review_id) AS reviews_count FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN reviews AS r ON p.product_id = r.product_id AND r.approved=1
GROUP BY products.product_id
```

Comment: thanks, but this would get me all the approved reviews, right? What I need is to get for example all approved reviews of a certain product only

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reviews
LEFT JOIN products ON reviews.product_id = products.product_id
LEFT JOIN categories ON products.category = categories.category_id
WHERE reviews.approved = 1 AND ...
ORDER BY reviews.review_date DESC
```